# Tip Jar splitting problem

Tags: complexity-theory

Having a bit of an issue with this question and deciding which of these situations requires dynamic programming and which are NP-complete. In all of these situations the input is a "tip jar" consisting of some number of coins/bills of the various types in D (e.g., five nickels, a dime and three quarters) and the problem is to determine whether the money in the jar can be divided equally between two people:

All three (except the last one) ask how much goes to person A and B if they split the amount down the middle :

A. There are N coins of an arbitrary number of different denominations, but each denomination is a power of 2 (I.E. 2 cents, 4 cents, etc.)

B. There are N bills of arbitrary denominations. In other words, 3 cents or 44, etc.

C. Same as B but now person A and B want to split the tips in two unequal parts provided the difference between them is less than 10 (I.E. |A| - |B| < 10).

My main question is which of these A B and C situations lead to the problem being in P and what makes it NP-complete.

Comment: Repost of http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/32284/9550

Comment: @DavidRicherby Duplicate votes are definitely in order.

Comment: If you want to improve your [former question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/32284/9550), please edit it (note the link below the post).

Comment: @Raphael Since this question has an answer, perhaps you should close the previous one and open this one? Alternatively, you can move my answer there.

Comment: You can repost, or I can merge. Which do you prefer?

Comment: I ended up reposting it.